# Trouble running bash command from bash script run from Python

Tags: python, eclipse, bash

I am running a bash script from Python. My IDE is Eclipse with PyDev. I have installed a software that has a bash command `bull2flux` that I want to run inside my bash script. `bull2flux` is usually run like this:

```
bull2flux someFile > outFile
```

The problem is that this works fine when it is invoked directly in the terminal, but not when running it from my python script. I get the error `bull2flux: command not found`. I have tried running the compiled version of my software from the terminal, but the same error occurs. Is this a problem with Eclipse? Do I have to source the command somehow? `bull2flux` is sourced in my `.bashrc` file like this:

```
source path/to/software/bin/init.sh /dev/null
```

Additional info: This is how I run it in my bash script:

```
for file in ${folder_bml_files}/*
do
    #Other stuff here
    bulledFile="bulltmp"
    bull2flux ${file} > ${bulledFile}
    #Other stuff here
done
```

Comment: Try calling using the full path of the scripts/programs.

Comment: This would probably work if the binary was placed in the same location for all users. I know that this particular software (and thus the binaries) has been installed in different locations for different users and thus it is better to source it in the `.bashrc` file in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the bull2flux executable is not in the PATH while your script is being executed. Try either using its full path or updating the PATH variable before calling the script.

**EDIT:** If bull2flux is just a shell function (not an executable), you might have to source the defining shell script from your script. Try adding the line

`source path/to/software/bin/init.sh /dev/null`

from your .bashrc to your own shell script.

Comment: Adding the binary to the PATH variable works fine. It seems the `source path/to/software/bin/init.sh /dev/null` does something different than this even though it also sets up `bull2flux` for use in the terminal. Thanks for pointing me in the rigth direction.